# T-SQL trigger after deleting

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

A need a trigger to run after a row is deleted from a table.
This trigger should delete rows from another table where a field on that table has a value matching the value of one of the columns of the deleted row from the other table.

Comment: You can't really delete columns, only rows. Changing/emptying a column is an update.

Comment: How do you mean "which column was deleted"?  Deletion affects all columns.  You can tell the row by looking in the `deleted` table.

Comment: It seems that OP needs to execute some code when a specific column ("field"?) was updated to an empty, null or zero value. I'm I right @JonnathanDurda

Comment: You have like 4 questions that are incomplete or make no sense.

Comment: What I am trying to do is catch what value was deleted from a specific column, in order to delete that value from another table.  I suppose I could do this by checking the deleted table with the specific column I need.

Comment: Suppose you could write a question that makes sense.  You are just going to continue to get down voted with questions of this quality.

Comment: Ah, makes sense - please see below

Answer (score 1):

If triggering the delete from a delete:

```
create trigger trg_mainTable
on dbo.mainTable
after delete
as
begin
    delete 
    from dbo.relatedTable
    where someColumn in 
    (
        select someColumn
        from deleted
    )
end
go
```

If triggering the delete from an update:

```
create trigger trg_mainTable
on dbo.mainTable
after update
as
begin
    if update(someColumn)
    begin
        delete 
        from dbo.relatedTable
        where someColumn in 
        (
            select someColumn
            from deleted
        )
    end
end
go
```

Comment: I am not buying your update.  You took it from an update trigger to a delete trigger.  Make the OP properly define the problem.

Comment: @Blam: added second answer per your comment.

Comment: I am not going to vote you down and you are still guessing.  Delete will have a value even if it is just changed (not deleted).  Make the OP define his question.  None of his question are clear.  I applaud your effort but in my opinion this is not good for SO.